# Specific Markers For Array of Google Map Places | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am setting a map using Google API where the user can select certain types of places like stores, parks, banks, etc in the surrounding area.

That part was no problem but now I would like to have different markers for each of the individual options. Like banks will have one marker, and parks would have another.

Right now they all use the same marker and I am struggling to understand how to make this work with Google Maps API.

My work so far is shown here.
http://codepen.io/carteralek/pen/zGmZzw

```js
var map;
var infoWindow;
var service;

var markersArray = [];
var options = ['bank', 'gas_station', 'post_office', 'library', 'police', 'hospital', 'museum', 'movie_theater', 'train_station', 'place_of_worship', 'school', 'grocery_or_supermarket', 'restaurant', 'shopping_center', 'department_store', 'home_goods_store', 'park'];

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.494718, -92.346826),
    zoom: 12,
    styles: [{
      stylers: [{
        visibility: 'simplified'
      }]
    }, {
      elementType: 'labels',
      stylers: [{
        visibility: 'off'
      }]
    }]


  });

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.494718, -92.346826);

  var bridgesMark = 'http://bridgessl.com/dev/wp-content/themes/ImpactMT/assets/img/mapMarker.png';
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    icon: bridgesMark,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', performSearch);
}

function performSearch() {
  clearMaps();
  var clickedOptions = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById(options[i]).checked) {
      clickedOptions.push(options[i]);
    }
  }

  var request = {
    bounds: map.getBounds(),
    types: clickedOptions
  };
  console.log
  service.radarSearch(request, callback);

}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    alert(status);
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
    createMarker(result);

  }
}

var image1 = 'http://bridgessl.com/dev/wp-content/themes/ImpactMT/assets/img/mapicons/bank.png';
var image2 = 'http://bridgessl.com/dev/wp-content/themes/ImpactMT/assets/img/mapicons/forest.png';

function createMarker(place) {

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location,
    icon: image1

  });


  markersArray.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    service.getDetails(place, function(result, status) {
      if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert(status);
        return;
      }
      infoWindow.setContent(result.name);
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('options').innerHTML += '<input type="checkbox" id="' + options[i] + '" onclick="performSearch();"> ' + options[i] + '<br>'
}


function clearMaps() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
    markersArray[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markersArray.length = 0;
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map-canvas {
  height: 70%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places,visualization"></script>
<div id="options"></div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: What are the markers you want to use for the places other than banks?

Comment: It will be difficult the way your code is currently structured.  A radarSearch doesn't include many of the properties of the place.  You will either need to do separate searches for each type of place (which will let you specify the icon) or do nearbySearch (which is limited to 60 results in groups of 20) which will contain the place type (and also a place icon).

Comment: @geocodezip I am Ideally hoping to use a separate marker for each of the options listed. Roughly 16 total types of markers.

Comment: @geocodezip Right now they can just be generic placeholders or standard google map markers. Once I know the code is working I can then focus on designing the individual icons.

Comment: As I said in my comment above, you will need to change your approach.  Are 20 results for each type OK?  A radarSearch request response will include up to 200 Places, identified only by their geographic coordinates and place_id, that isn't enough information to determine the icon to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to do separate searches for each type, passing the icon you prefer in to the search routine.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rn92mkkn/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var infoWindow;
var service;

var markersArray = [];
var options = ['bank', 'gas_station', 'post_office', 'library', 'police', 'hospital', 'museum', 'movie_theater', 'train_station', 'place_of_worship', 'school', 'grocery_or_supermarket', 'restaurant', 'shopping_center', 'department_store', 'home_goods_store', 'park'];

function getLetteredIcon(letter) {
  return "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + letter + ".png";
}

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.494718, -92.346826),
    zoom: 12,
    styles: [{
      stylers: [{
        visibility: 'simplified'
      }]
    }, {
      elementType: 'labels',
      stylers: [{
        visibility: 'off'
      }]
    }]


  });

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.494718, -92.346826);

  var bridgesMark = 'http://bridgessl.com/dev/wp-content/themes/ImpactMT/assets/img/mapMarker.png';
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    icon: bridgesMark,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', performSearch);

  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('options').innerHTML += '<input type="checkbox" id="' + options[i] + '" onclick="performSearch();"> <img src=' + getLetteredIcon(String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + i)) + ' height="20" /> ' + options[i] + '<br>';

  }

}

function performSearch() {
  clearMaps();
  var clickedOptions = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById(options[i]).checked) {
      performTypeSearch(options[i], getLetteredIcon(String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + i)));
    }
  }
}

function performTypeSearch(type, icon) {
  var request = {
    bounds: map.getBounds(),
    types: [type]
  };
  service.radarSearch(request, function(results, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      alert(type + ":" + status);
      return;
    }
    for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
      createMarker(result, icon);

    }
  });
}

function createMarker(place, icon) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location,
    icon: icon

  });
  markersArray.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    service.getDetails(place, function(result, status) {
      if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert(status);
        return;
      }
      infoWindow.setContent(result.name);
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  });
}



function clearMaps() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
    markersArray[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markersArray.length = 0;
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map-canvas {
  height: 70%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places,visualization"></script>
<div id="options"></div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: That seems to work great! Thanks for clearing that up, this was my first stackoverflow submission so I wasnt too hopeful but this is exactly what I was going for.

Answer (score 0):

When to choose to draw the markers on the map you need to swap out the icon. It could be as simple as changing this:

```
var image1 = 'http://bridgessl.com/dev/wp-content/themes/ImpactMT/assets/img/mapicons/bank.png';
var image2 = 'http://bridgessl.com/dev/wp-content/themes/ImpactMT/assets/img/mapicons/forest.png';


// added in new param for iconpath
function createMarker(place, iconpath) {

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location,
    icon: iconpath // lets use the iconpath

  });

...
```

and calling it with `crateMarker(..., image1);`